# Can i write Kafka consumer in java api to consume messages produced by python producer

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have producer code written in python which fetches tweets from twitter. I have created the topic named twitter_test.

When i use kafka-console-consumer i can see that there are lot tweets in that topic.

But when i tried to  consume this messages from java consumer it is not fetching any data.

Below is my consumer code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class avro_twitter {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.16.111.12:9092");
     props.put("group.id", "groupid");

     props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
     props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
     props.put("schema.registry.url", "10.16.111.12:8081"); 
     String topic = "twitter_test";

     KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
     System.out.println("Reading topic:" + topic);


     while (true) { 

         ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = consumer.poll(1000); 
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record: records) {
             String authid=record.value().get(1).toString();
             String screen_name=record.value().get(1).toString();
             String description=record.value().get(2).toString();     


             System.out.println(authid);

         }   
         }
     }
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: 1. Any exceptions? 2. Did you try changing group id? 3. Did you try consuming raw messages without Avro decode?

Comment: Could you please also share the producer code? The following code snippet looks at least a little strange: props.put("group.id", "groupid");

Comment: Did you registered your avro schema at the schema registry?